# A (surprising?) expression for $e$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I apologise if this is off topic.

Consider the quantity
$$
F(m,n,k)=\frac{(m)_k}{k!n^{k-1} }
$$
where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}.$ For moderately large $n$, it seems that the approximation
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{K} k F(n,n,k) \approx en,
$$
where $K$ is the largest integer $k$ for which $k!\leq n,$
is excellent with the quality of approximation essentially independent of $n\in [10^2,10^6].$

There must be a (deep?) mathematical reason for this, I feel. Any comments, references, pointers welcome.

Comment: I'm confused about a detail. Is $(m)_k = m(m-1)(m-2) \cdots (m-k+1)$? If so, then $F(n,n,k)=0$ for $k > n$, so $F(n,n,k)<1$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, yes, but my sum is restricted to $k$ much smaller than $n.$

Comment: You write "$K$ is the largest integer $k$ for which $F(n,n,k) \leq 1$."

Comment: Fixed typo, I had a normalised version going earlie, and failed to update.

Comment: I get that the asymtotics of the corrected sum are $en$, not $e^{-1} n$. Indeed, the $k=1$ term is $n$ and all terms are positive, so $e^{-1} n$ can't be right. Another typo?

Comment: Please include some numerical data that illustrates how the approximation is "excellent, with the quality of approximation essentially independent of $n \in [10^2,10^6]$".

Comment: The asymtotic analysis mentioned in the previous comment is as follows: Since $k! \leq n$, we have $k = o(\log n)$, so $\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (n-j)/n = 1-O(k^2/n) = 1-o(1)$ and we have $(n)_k = n^k (1-o(1))$. Thus the sum is $\sum_{k=1}^K \tfrac{k n^k (1-o(1))}{k! n^{k-1}} = n (1-o(1))  \sum_{k=1}^K \tfrac{1}{(k-1)!} = n e (1-o(1))$. There are some details of uniformity to be checked, but it also sounds like there are more typos to be found.

Comment: I think what you observe is that the main contribution to $\sum_k\binom{n}{k}kn^{-k}$ comes from the first few terms, that is, those with $k! \leq n$, right?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, the quantity is indeed $en$.

Comment: You can see the phenomenon in WolframAlpha for the case $n=10^4, K=7$ with Sum[Factorial[n] / (Factorial[n-k] Factorial[k-1] n^k), {k,1,7}, {n,10000,10000}]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BFactorial%5Bn%5D%2F(Factorial%5Bn-k%5DFactorial%5Bk-1%5Dn%5Ek),%7Bk,1,7%7D,%7Bn,10000,10000%7D%5D

Comment: ...which means is this just looking at the beginning terms of $\sum k \binom{n}{k} /n^k$, which is just $(1+1/n)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MattF. and MartinRubey thanks. I am happy to accept if you type an answer. Otherwise I shall type it up so the question doesn't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typing in the answer from the comments so the question does not stay "unanswered".

The expression on the left can be rewritten
$$
\sum_{k} k \binom{n}{k}  n^{-k}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1},
$$ and the contribution to the sum comes from the very few first terms, those with $k!\leq n.$